# Arduino Uno: Running multiple servos

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I have a Arduino Uno, and I am pretty new to the Arduino stuff. I am new to circuits also. I am thinking about working on a simple spider robot and making it more complex as I learn about the Arduino. Anyways, yesterday I tried seeing if I could run 10 server motors (small ones) with the Arduino. I linked all the positive wires in parrel and connected it to the 5v on the board. I observed that not all the servers moved like the code says. I looked it up and found out I can't do that or else I might fry it. I did not fry it thank goodness. I then found out that I have to have a separate power supply and connect the servers red wires(positive wire) to the power supplies red wire and connect the ground wires to ground on the Arduino. I found this picture showing this.

https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+uno+connecting+multiple+servos&biw=1920&bih=974&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU5r6ovv7RAhVp5oMKHV_cDqAQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=DmQfCRVK9SXwAM:

I also saw that in another forum someone said something about using  a capacitor. So I have some questions still. My first question is do I have to have a capacitor or can I just do what the picture in the link I gave does? It shows the power supply being a 6v NiMH 2800 mAh battery. I looked online I could not find that exact same battery with a charger, but I found this on ebay.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/121963271143

So I thought if I connect 5 of the batteries in series that way the amps is left alone for 2800 mAh and 6v, the exact spec of the battery in the picture. So my second question is will this work? I have this pack from Radio Shack near my house that I got. 
https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-8-aa-battery-holder#

There is a problem with this one though and that is it holds 8 and not 5. So my third question is will it still work with only 5 batteries in it? The forth question is how do I connect the wires to this item since it has no wires coming off of it? My fifth question is are these battery packs connected in series since they add the volts? Thank you for reading this and taking your time to clear up my confusion. I will restate the questions down below.

1. Do I have to have a capacitor or can I just do what the picture in the first link I gave does?
2. Will this work?

Connecting 5 of the batteries in series that way the amps is left alone for 2800 mAh and 6v, the exact spec of the battery in the picture.

3. Will it still work with only 5 batteries in the 8 battery holder?
4. How do I connect the wires to this battery holder since it has no wires coming off of it?
5. Are these battery packs connected in series since they add the volts?

Again, thank you for reading this long forum question and thank you for your time.

Comment: This question appears to be **off-topic** for *Stackoverflow* since it has nothing to do with programming. You should post it at [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, thanks and I am going to delete some lines to since I found out some things that answered some of my questions.